# Empty the contents of a database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a huge data base with complicated relations, how can I delete all tables contents without violating foreign key constraints,is there a a such way to do that?

note that I am writing a SQL script file to delete tables such as the following example:

```
delete from A
delete from B
delete from C
delete from D
delete from E
```

but I don't know what table should I start with.

Comment: notee that i dont want to drop the whole DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, there is no native way to do what you're asking. You do have a few options depending on your particular environment limitations:

1. Figure out the relationships between the tables and start deleting rows out in the appropriate order from foreigns to parents. This may be time-consuming for a large number of objects, but is the "safest" in terms of least destruction.
2. Disable the foreign key constraints and TRUNCATE TABLE. This will be a bit faster if you're dealing with lots of data, but you still have to to know where all your relationships are. Not too terrible if you're working with fewer tables, though option 1 becomes just as viable
3. Script out the database objects and DROP DATABASE/CREATE DATABASE. If you don't care about a raw teardown of the database, this is another option, however, you'll still need to be aware of object precedence for creation. SQL Server—as well as third-party tools— offer ways to script object DROP/CREATE. If you decide to go this route, the upside is that you have a scripted backup of all the objects (which I like to keep "just in case") and future tear-downs are nearly instantaneous as long as you keep your scripts synchronized with any changes.

As you can see, it's not a terribly simple process because you're trying to subvert the very reason for the existence of the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Steps can be:

1. disable all the constraint in all the tables
2. delete all the records from all the tables
3. enable the constraint back again.

Also see this discussion: [SQL: delete all the data from all available tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832160/sql-delete-all-the-data-from-all-available-tables)

Comment: Thank you i think this is very good solution ,i will test it in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tableName
```

> Removes all rows from a table without
>   logging the individual row deletions.
>   TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the
>   DELETE statement with no WHERE clause;
>   however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and
>   uses fewer system and transaction log
>   resources.

[TRUNCATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

Comment: sorry but i want a script to run it in c# program this script should contains a number of delete table statements is this ok for you ???

Comment: yes ,now should i sort the the tables so that the tables which contains FK deleted first and tables with Pk deleted last??

Comment: @qablan89: you need to **drop** all FK constraints, then use `TRUNCATE TABLE`  and then re-create the constraints - no other way to do it

Comment: @marc_s: maybe he can, i guess if he started with the tables that have no constraints, `cascade deleting`... then delete the tables that have..

Answer (score 0):

Dude, taking your question at face value... that you want to COMPLETELY recreate the schema with NO data... forget the individual queries (too slow)... just destroydb, and then createdb (or whatever your RDBM's equivalent is)... and you might want to hire a competent DBA.