# How to drop and create schema multiple times?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to drop-and-create tables multiple times using JPA/EclipseLink (2.5.1) on a JUnit test by calling `createEntityManager` on an `EntityManagerFactory` instantiated multiple times. However, the schema is dropped/created only once. How to make EclipseLink drop/create the schema every time?

My ultimate goal is to have the db tables in a known state (i.e. empty) for each test. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: and how are you doing this? so then people know what to comment on. Creating a new EMF for each test? JPA 2.1 has properties to do a drop+create at EMF creation if that is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating the schema on every test run will slow down your tests considerably. You simply need to ensure your data is in a 'known state', in your case all tables empty. So:

Run your tests in a transaction marked as 'rollback only' so the database returns to a known state after each execution.

and/or

have a look at either DBUnit which you can use to put your database in a known state before each test run.

http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/index.html

or

http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: I ended up implementing the notion of putting the db in a "known state" before each test i.e. in my case delete data from all tables. I looked into DBUnit but found no notion of deleting all the data from *all* tables. I ended up using Jdbc directly to [delete all the data from my Oracle db](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11030009/614800)

Answer (score 2):

With EclipseLink, I used have used

```
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "drop-and-create-tables");
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
properties.put("eclipselink.deploy-on-startup", "true");
```

Then

```
JpaHelper.getEntityManagerFactory(em).refreshMetadata(properties);
```

This drops and recreates tables for all entities in the persistence unit.  As mentioned elsewhere, calling this multiple times is expensive - you are better off clearing data before/after a test using the JPA bulk delete queries:

```
  "DELETE from EntityName entity"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill for your application, but I've used Liquibase to handle versioning of DB schema and table contents.  It should be straightforward to tie in pre/post hooks for your JUnit code.