# How to delete data from specified tables at once in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have more than 40 tables in `RATOR_MONITORING` schema for which the table name is starting from `'TEMP_'`. I want to delete data from all such tables at once in a single query instead of using delete statement for each and every table. I dont even want to generate statements. I can create anonymous block if required but dont know how to do that. I tried below query but its not working.

```
Delete from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.'%TEMP_';
```

Comment: You should generate DML and use dynamic sql in pl\sql block, just lurk `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement

Comment: As i said i dont want to generate sql statement because i want to try this logic in different schemas and every time then i have to generate sql statements and use dynamic sql in pl\sql block. But can you please give an example of what you said ?

Comment: You have to generate DML, there is no way to do such task without it. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832160/sql-delete-all-the-data-from-all-available-tables there is examples close to your task. Look at example with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: Just a tip for future reference: saying *"I don't want to X"* is not helpful in a technical discussion. *"I believe that I can't/shouldn't do X because of Y"* is much more helpful and will get a more useful response.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp ok i will take care about this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all the rows, then better use **TRUNCATE**, it will reset the **high watermark**. But remember, truncate is a **DDL** statement, and thus there will be an **implicit commit**; With **DELETE** you can commit manually after validation.

Although, I would not do that in a production environment. If it is something you are doing in test environment to build test data, then you could (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**.

For example, execute the following anonymous block as `RATOR_MONITORING` user:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables where table_name like 'TEMP%'
  )
  LOOP
    v_sql := 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||i.table_name;
    EXECUTE immediate v_sql;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

By the way, using a good **text editor**, it won't take more than a minute to build DELETE/TRUNCATE statements and do it in **pure SQL**.

Comment: Hello Lalit i dont want to delete data from the tables in schema. I want to delete data from Rator_Monitoring_Configuration schema for which the table name is starting from 'TEMP_' and yes i am trying this query in test environment first and if it works then i will use in production enevironment.

Comment: @Rahul No problem, just add a filter to the query in the for loop. I have updated the code.

Comment: I dont understood lalit why we have to use user_tables in select query Instead of providing schema name ?

Comment: @Rahul `user_tables` will have all the table_names, from which you will filter those tables starting with `TEMP%`. Without mentioning the table_name explicitly, you cannot execute the delete statement?